# Tracking a git branch issue

Tags: git, git-branch

I have cloned a repo using git. Another user created a new branch, call it foo (there are so two branches master and foo). I created another branch foo to track remote foo. So I ran this command : git branch --set-upstream foo origin/foo. But I have an error message telling me  : `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'origin/foo'` Can anybody help ? When I run git remote origin show I have the message :

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://***
  Push  URL: ssh://***
  HEAD branch: foo
  Remote branches:
    master   tracked
    foo new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (local out of date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must first fetch or pull the branch up to your local repo.

```
git fetch origin
# OR
git pull origin
```

After that, you can checkout `foo`

```
git checkout foo
```

And, you could use the above command you wrote to track origin/foo with another local branch name (put in your call, just checkout as you use the same name anyway).

Git remote are only somewhere you can pull/push change. But in reality, all what git do is on your local drive, so you cannot interact with remote branch unless you fetch them first to your locale. `origin/foo` is only a label on a `sha-1` commit id that you hold locally. When you use `origin/foo`, you reference the local label, not the remote status (there's no ssh connection made while referencing a remote branch).

Comment: Nice ! Btw a question : in fact when I clone a repo, I only pull the master branch. Then I need to run the command you cited to get all the remote branches, (so then I can track them ), right?

Comment: No, when you clone, you get all branches. You always clone the full git repository as it is a DVCS (Distributed version control system). Although, you clone the full repository from where it is keeped, if a fellow programmer have a local branch that he didn't push to your remote, this one will be out of reach (unless you use his local repo as a remote).